# How to save svg canvas to local filesystem

Tags: javascript, svg, save, filesystems, local

Is there a way to allow a user, after he has created a vector graph on a javascript svg canvas using a browser, to download this file to their local filesystem?

SVG is a total new field for me so please be patient if my wording is not accurate.

Comment: I answered a similar question in more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379923/save-svg-image-rendered-by-a-javascript-to-local-disk-as-png-file/8861315#8861315

Comment: I finally have a working implementation: http://www.iscriptdesign.com . Choose svg export. Verified for latest Firefox & chrome

Comment: There are some browser extensions that allow downloading SVG files. Some of them also keep the style info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might be possible using the regular "Save" browser command, but it won't just save the SVG canvas, it will save the whole page.

I believe your best bet is to use AJAX and send the whole SVG XML data as POST data to a server script, and have that script just send back the POST data with the header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=yourfile.svg`.

(Under PHP, you can get the raw POST contents with `file_get_contents('php://input')`.)

Comment: How should we handle the response in this case?

Answer (score 64):

You can avoid a round trip to the server.

Base64 encode your SVG xml.

Then generate a link to that data.  The user can right click on to save it locally.

```
// This example was created using Protovis & jQuery
// Base64 provided by http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html
// Modern web browsers have a builtin function to this as well 'btoa'
function encode_as_img_and_link(){
 // Add some critical information
 $("svg").attr({ version: '1.1' , xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"});

 var svg = $("#chart-canvas").html();
 var b64 = Base64.encode(svg); // or use btoa if supported

 // Works in recent Webkit(Chrome)
 $("body").append($("<img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,\n"+b64+"' alt='file.svg'/>"));

 // Works in Firefox 3.6 and Webit and possibly any browser which supports the data-uri
 $("body").append($("<a href-lang='image/svg+xml' href='data:image/svg+xml;base64,\n"+b64+"' title='file.svg'>Download</a>"));
}
```

The img tag works in Webkit, the link works in Webkit & Firefox, and may work in any browser which supports `data-uri`

Comment: Where does `Base64` come from?

Comment: This example is using the library from http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

Comment: This is totally the cleanest solution and it *almost* works: Chrome displays the image from data-uri correctly, but it doesn't let you save! Firefox is worse, as it garbles the data somehow. *sigh*

Comment: I have no experience with it, but there is the HTML FileSystem api.  It will allow writing files (in a current browser).  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Using HTML5 you also can add the `download` attribute to your link, which makes it a bit easier for the user.
[See here](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) for more info

Comment: In case the text contains Unicode characters, use `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg)))`—no libraries required.

Answer (score 19):

Using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

```
saveAs(new Blob([SVG_DATA_HERE], {type:"image/svg+xml"}), "name.svg")
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? it's not saving the SVG on the local filesystem is it?

Comment: Scott: This opens the SVG in it's own page, where the user can save it to their filesystem by themself.

Comment: When I try it, I get the following error: "This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty" - but the error may be on my side. I know I'm throwing in the right data, so I don't know _which_ error it is.

Comment: How can I extract the `SVG_DATA`? `document.getElementsByTagName("svg")<something to get the data>`

Comment: @yckart: document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[i].parentNode.innerHTML, where i is the key of the svg you want to export in the HTMLCollectionr returned by document.get..., if you have only one svn tag in the page then i=0.

Comment: If you're using FabricJS:
`var filedata = canvas.toSVG();
saveAs(new Blob([filedata], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}), "export.svg");`

Answer (score 18):

There is no need to do base64 encoding - you can create a link with raw SVG code in it. Here is a modified function encode_as_img_and_link() from The_Who's answer:

```
function img_and_link() {
  $('body').append(
    $('<a>')
      .attr('href-lang', 'image/svg+xml')
      .attr('href', 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' +  unescape($('svg')[0].outerHTML))
      .text('Download')
  );
}
```

Comment: This answer should be up-voted. The second parameter of `.attr('href', ...)` is effectively the raw `<svg>...</svg>` code. Works on Chrome and Safari though I've not gotten it to work on Edge. IE seems to be a no-go across the board.

Comment: For me, this broke when the source svg has an xmlns URL ending with '#'.

Answer (score 11):

With [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) from Eli Grey I got it working (chrome):

```
bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder;
var svg = $('#designpanel').svg('get');
bb.append(svg.toSVG());
var blob = bb.getBlob("application/svg+xml;charset=" + svg.characterSet);
saveAs(blob,"name.svg");
```

SVG is from keith woods jquery's svg.

[Html Rocks 1](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

[Html Rocks 2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-writing)

Answer (score 7):

```js
 // save SVG
 $('#SVGsave').click(function(){
  var a      = document.createElement('a');
  a.href     = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + unescape($('#SVG')[0].outerHTML);
  a.download = 'plot.svg';
  a.target   = '_blank';
  document.body.appendChild(a); a.click(); document.body.removeChild(a);
 });
```

Comment: You saved may day! I would give you a stackoverflow-gold if it existed!

Answer (score 6):

I recently found this Chrome plugin http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/. It's a bit buggy for my needs but essentially works.

I had previously made a solution similar to the accepted answer which involved a serverside script but it's quite long winded and also had the problem that all the styles had to be inline in the markup. Crowbar seems to take care of that for you, which is nice.

Comment: This also saves the CSS style info, nice.

Comment: In what ways was it buggy?

Answer (score 5):

I'm replying to this topic, even though it's a few years old, because the recent convergence of web browsers in their support for SVG and other relevant behaviour has produced renewed interest in SVG and allows a 'universal' answer to the question. In essence zneak's approach is correct but, in my opinion, terse (i.e. it took me a while to get it working for myself). I also think that his reference to AJAX is either unnecessary or not what I understand by AJAX (= uses an XMLHttpRequest). I shall therefore provide a more detailed answer using pure JavaScript (i.e. without JQuery or any other library) and provide server code for Java, Perl and PHP.

(1) Have the (dynamically generated) SVG content in your HTML page enclosed in a div with a unique ID, e.g.

`<div id="svg"><svg...>SVG content</svg></div>`

(2) Include a button to invoke the JavaScript function, e.g.

`<button onclick="sendSVG();">Save as SVG File</button>`

(3) Include the JavaScript function named in your button markup:

```
function sendSVG() 
{
   var svgText = document.getElementById('svg').innerHTML;

   var form = document.createElement("form");
   form.setAttribute("method", "post");
   form.setAttribute("action", "http://path-to-your-server-app");
   form.setAttribute("accept-charset", "UTF-8");

   var hiddenSVGField = document.createElement("input");    
   hiddenSVGField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
   hiddenSVGField.setAttribute("name", "svgText");
   hiddenSVGField.setAttribute("value", svgText);

   form.appendChild(hiddenSVGField);
   document.body.appendChild(form);
   form.submit();
}
```

(4) Write a server app to accept your SVGtext post request and return as image/svg+xml using Content-Disposition to specify an attachment. Working code in three languages is presented, although I am not a Perl programmer and have never used PHP in anger.

Java Servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
   String svgText = (String) request.getParameter("svgText");
   response.setContentType("image/svg+xml");
   response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"image.svg\"");
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.println(svgText);
}
```

Perl CGI

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
my $svgText = param('svgText');
print header(-type => "image/svg+xml",
    -content_disposition => "attachment; filename=image.svg");      
print $svgText;
```

PHP

```
<?php
   $svgText = $_POST['svgText'];
   header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.svg"'); 
   print "$svgText";
?>
```

I have used a hard-coded name for the image here (image.svg), but actually pick up a discriptor of the dynamic content I generate from the page (using a div and an ID again, and `document.getElementById('graphName').textContent`).

This has been tested on Mac Safari 9, Firefox 42, Chrome 47, Opera 34, and Windows7/IE 11 and Windows10/Edge and in each case the svg file is downloaded or one is prompted to download it. The resulting files will open in, e.g. Adobe Illustrator or whatever other application you have set to open svg files.

A real-world example of this (if you consider academic research real-world) is at http://flyatlas.gla.ac.uk/MidgutAtlas/index.html in the Gene section.

Answer (score 2):

Yes is it possible. Use jquery.svg http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html and post the svg xml data using the function svg.toSVG() (writing into a hidden field on submit). 
Have the php save and convert to raster using imagemagick (convert image.svg image.png) then force the file to download using header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream") and readfile the image.

Answer (score 1):

Most compatible way would be a round-trip to the server. You could also use a [data: URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in some browsers.

Comment: All the browsers that support SVG support data uri:s too, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You can't save anything with javascript to the local filesystem, what you should do is send the contents of the `canvas` to the server and make the user download and save that.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

Another possibility though not the nicest is to display the serialized contents on the webpage and have the user select, copy and paste that. 
This after investigating eli grey's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I maybe discovered a better way for not forcing the user to press right click "save image as". just live draw the canvas base64 code into the href of the link and modify it so the download will start automatically. i dont know if its universal browser compatible but it should work with the main/new browsers.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('your-canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var C = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

$('#your-canvas').mousedown(function(event) {
    // feel free to choose your event ;) 

    // just for example
    // var OFFSET = $(this).offset();
    // var x = event.pageX - OFFSET.left;
    // var y = event.pageY - OFFSET.top;

    // standard data to url
    var imgdata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    // modify the dataUrl so the browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newdata = imgdata.replace(/^data:image\/png/,'data:application/octet-stream');
    // give the link the values it needs
       $('a.linkwithnewattr').attr('download','your_pic_name.png').attr('href',newdata);

});
```

feel free to wrap the a around anything you want, hope that helps a bit

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#btnDownload").click(function(){
 var $container = $('#svg-container'),
     // Canvg requires trimmed content
    content = $container.html().trim(),
    canvas = document.getElementById('svg-canvas');
 
 // Draw svg on canvas
    canvg(canvas, content);
 $container.hide();
    // Change img be SVG representation
    var theImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
 
 var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = theImage; // xhr.response es un blob file
 a.target = '_blank';
 a.download = 'prueba'; // nombre del archivo.
 a.style.display = 'none';
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.click();
 delete a;
});//fin function
});// fin
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/canvg.js"></script> 
<input id="svgData" name="svgData" type="hidden"/>
<input id="btnDownload" type="button" value="Descargar"/>
<div id='svg-container'>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="400"><desc>Created with Highcharts 4.0.4</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-5"><rect x="-75" y="-75" width="750" height="550"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="400" strokeWidth="0" fill="#FFFFFF" class=" highcharts-background"></rect><g  style="stroke:rgba(255,255,255,0);"><path fill="rgb(255,255,255)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 59 79 L 460 61 L 456 287 L 65 330 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(255,255,255)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 65 330 L 456 287 L 456 286 L 65 330 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(230,230,230)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 0 0"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  style="stroke:rgba(255,255,255,0);"><path fill="rgb(255,255,255)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 495 66 L 496 66 L 490 300 L 490 301 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(230,230,230)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 495 66 L 460 61 L 455 287 L 490 301 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(255,255,255)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 495 66 L 460 61 L 460 61 L 496 66 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  style="stroke:rgba(255,255,255,0);"><path fill="rgb(255,255,255)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 88 345 L 490 300 L 490 300 L 88 346 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(255,255,255)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 88 346 L 490 300 L 457 287 L 65 330 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(230,230,230)" fill-opacity="0" d="M 88 345 L 65 329 L 65 330 L 88 346 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid" ><path fill="none" d="M 146 75 L 146 75 L 150 320 L 175 336" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 189 73 L 189 73 L 191 316 L 217 331" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 230 71 L 230 71 L 232 311 L 259 326" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 271 69 L 271 69 L 271 307 L 300 322" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 310 67 L 310 67 L 310 302 L 339 317" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 349 66 L 349 66 L 348 298 L 378 313" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 387 64 L 387 64 L 385 294 L 416 308" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 424 62 L 424 62 L 421 290 L 454 304" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 461 61 L 461 61 L 457 286 L 491 300" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 103 77 L 103 77 L 108 325 L 131 341" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 59 79 L 59 79 L 65 329 L 87 345" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid" ><path fill="none" d="M 59 78 L 59 78 L 461 60 L 496 66" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 61 144 L 61 144 L 460 119 L 494 127" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 62 206 L 62 206 L 459 175 L 493 185" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 64 269 L 64 269 L 458 232 L 492 243" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 65 330 L 65 330 L 457 286 L 490 300" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-axis" ><path fill="none" d="M 75 325.5 L 525 325.5" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"  visibility="hidden"></path></g><g class="highcharts-axis" ><text x="556.96875"  text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(90 556.96875 200)" class=" highcharts-yaxis-title" style="color:#707070;fill:#707070;" visibility="visible" y="200">Values</text></g><g class="highcharts-series-group" ><g class="highcharts-series" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(75,75) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-5)"><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 390 141 L 408 139 L 406 226 L 388 228 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 390 141 L 378 137 L 376 223 L 388 228 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 390 141 L 378 137 L 395 136 L 408 139 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 353 56 L 372 54 L 369 230 L 351 232 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 353 56 L 342 53 L 339 227 L 351 232 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 353 56 L 342 53 L 360 52 L 372 54 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 314 118 L 333 117 L 332 235 L 313 237 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 314 118 L 303 114 L 302 231 L 313 237 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 314 118 L 303 114 L 322 113 L 333 117 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 275 212 L 294 210 L 293 239 L 274 241 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 275 212 L 264 207 L 283 205 L 294 210 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 275 212 L 264 207 L 264 236 L 274 241 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 235 94 L 255 93 L 254 243 L 235 246 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 235 94 L 224 90 L 224 240 L 235 246 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 235 94 L 224 90 L 244 89 L 255 93 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 194 250 L 214 248 L 214 248 L 194 250 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 194 250 L 184 245 L 204 243 L 214 248 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 194 250 L 184 245 L 184 245 L 194 250 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 152 131 L 173 130 L 173 253 L 153 255 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 152 131 L 142 127 L 143 249 L 153 255 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 152 131 L 142 127 L 163 126 L 173 130 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 66 170 L 88 168 L 89 262 L 68 264 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 66 170 L 57 165 L 59 259 L 68 264 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 66 170 L 57 165 L 79 163 L 88 168 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g><g  r="0" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"><path fill="#7cb5ec" d="M 23 206 L 44 204 L 45 267 L 24 269 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(99,156,211)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 23 206 L 14 201 L 15 264 L 24 269 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path><path fill="rgb(149,206,255)" fill-opacity="1" d="M 23 206 L 14 201 L 36 199 L 44 204 Z"  stroke-linejoin="round"></path></g></g><g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(75,75) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"></g></g><text x="300" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title"  style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;fill:#333333;width:536px;" y="25"><tspan>3D chart with null values</tspan></text><text x="300" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-subtitle"  style="color:#555555;fill:#555555;width:536px;" y="53"><tspan>Notice the difference between a 0 value and a null point</tspan></text><g class="highcharts-legend"  transform="translate(270,364)"><g ><g><g class="highcharts-legend-item"  transform="translate(8,3)"><text x="21" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"  y="15">Sales</text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12"  fill="#7cb5ec"></rect></g></g></g></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" ><text x="110" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="363" z="-59" opacity="1">Jan</text><text x="154" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="358" z="-40" opacity="1">Feb</text><text x="197" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="353" z="-22" opacity="1">Mar</text><text x="239" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="348" z="-3" opacity="1">Apr</text><text x="280" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="343" z="16" opacity="1">May</text><text x="320" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="338" z="35" opacity="1">Jun</text><text x="359" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="334" z="53" opacity="1">Jul</text><text x="398" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="329" z="72" opacity="1">Aug</text><text x="435" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="324" z="91" opacity="1">Sep</text><text x="472" text-anchor="middle" style="width:25px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="320" z="109" opacity="1">Oct</text></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels" ><text x="502" text-anchor="start" style="width:55px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="301" z="122" opacity="1">0</text><text x="504" text-anchor="start" style="width:55px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="244" z="111" opacity="1">2</text><text x="505" text-anchor="start" style="width:55px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="187" z="100" opacity="1">4</text><text x="506" text-anchor="start" style="width:55px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="128" z="90" opacity="1">6</text><text x="508" text-anchor="start" style="width:55px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="69" z="79" opacity="1">8</text></g><g class="highcharts-tooltip"  style="cursor:default;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;" transform="translate(0,-9999)"><path fill="none" d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="none" d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="none" d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.15" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="rgb(249, 249, 249)" fill-opacity=" .85" d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"></path><text x="8"  style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="21"></text></g><text x="590" text-anchor="end"  style="cursor:pointer;color:#909090;font-size:9px;fill:#909090;" y="395">Highcharts.com</text></svg>

</div>
<section>
 <canvas id="svg-canvas"></canvas>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

No need to do any programming at all. There are online apps people have already built for that, and include definable parameters such as dimensions, resolution, output format etc.

This is one of the better online image conversion apps I've found for svg->jpeg.http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.