# How to export angularjs-nvd3 chart to a file

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

I would like to use nvd3 chart library in my AngularJS app by using angularjs-nvd3-directives
Is there a way to export any given nvd3 chart to any of the graphics file formats?

Comment: Did you find some way to do it? I'm now taking a look on saving SVG to server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379923/save-svg-image-rendered-by-a-javascript-to-local-disk-as-png-file/8861315#8861315

Comment: So far, I  have not found a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

**Please post a code sample for detailed help**

## To capture your chart to a file for use

- Register a callback in `on-ready` in your nvd3 directive. This callback receives a 2 parameters as show below

`$scope.callback = function(scope,element){
        $scope.myChartScope = scope;
    }`

This `$scope.myChartScope` should contain a reference to your svg element, console.log it to see its contents

- In your options object for the line chart, there is a `dispatch` object which has an attribute called `renderEnd` that gets called when your chart is fully drawn. In this `renderEnd` you can then access your `$scope.myChartScope.svg` 
  and then do what you want with it.

  > You can use a library like https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng to save your SVG to an image file
  >   **All done on the client side**

I hope this answers your question!