# Save SVG Diagram from HTM Button

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Is there any way that you can have a button on a HTML page, which saves a diagram that you have created.

My model is a flower creator which uses shapes in SVG and creates the flower. Now after the diagram is made. Id like a button to save the diagram from the SVG ViewBox that i have.

And a button to print if possible.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save svg canvas to local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483919/how-to-save-svg-canvas-to-local-filesystem)

Comment: Ive tred that thread and it was not useful for me sorry. Its ok now thanks ive got it sorted