# Save SVG-Data in File

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I'm using the **[svgcanvas.js](https://code.google.com/p/html5-canvas-svg/)** to create SVG and trying to save the svgcode.

With the normal canvas content, I could save the resulting png as below: toDataURL and with window.location.href the save as Dialog appeared in my Browser.

With the SVG, the SVG appears in the URL. How can I make the Browser save the SVG-Code as File?

```
var ctx = new CanvasSVG( "#SVG" );
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#333333";
ctx.fillRect( 10 , 10 , 50 , 50 );
ctx.closePath();

document.getElementById( "xml" ).innerHTML = ctx.toDataURL( "image/svg+xml" );
var image=ctx.toDataURL( "image/svg+xml" );
window.location.href=image;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save svg canvas to local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483919/how-to-save-svg-canvas-to-local-filesystem)