# Saving d3js plot locally

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, save

I am creating a plot using d3js. I also want to give the ability to the user to save that plot locally at his computer. Therefore, I used a slightly changed version of the code mentioned at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483919/how-to-save-svg-canvas-to-local-filesystem) to create a downloadable picture of that plot.

So I have the following code:

```
$("svg").attr({ version: '1.1' , xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"});

var svg = $("#chart-main").html();  var b64 = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg)));//Base64.encode(svg); // or use btoa if supported

// Works in recent Webkit(Chrome)  
$("body").append($("<img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,\n"+b64+"' alt='file.svg'/>"));


 // Works in Firefox 3.6 and Webit and possibly any browser which supports the data-uri
  $("body").append($("<a href-lang='image/svg+xml' href='data:image/svg+xml;base64,\n"+b64+"' title='file.svg'>Download</a>"));
```

However, when I press on the download link I get the following error:
This page contains the following errors:

> error on line 6 at column 16:
>   Entity 'nbsp' not defined

The link is like `data:image/svg+xml;base64,CgkJCQkJP....CgkJCQk=`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `&nbsp;` is an HTML entity.

A stand-alone SVG file, as an XML format, only supports the five pre-defined XML entities: `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;`, and `&gt;`.

To represent any other unicode character, however, you can use a character reference based on the unicode value.  The code for a non-breaking space is `&#160;`.  Use this to replace `&nbsp;` and your SVG file should validate.

P.S.  I find [FileFormat.info's character search site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) useful for looking up Unicode values.