# BPMN to Image convertor

Tags: bpmn, oryx

Our client is using oryx editor to render bpmn in browser .Now they have asked me to capture the image of the Bpmn diagram and save it. Is there any thing in java or javascript that can change BPMN to jpeg,svg format.

Please tell me how can I do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/wiki/DatabaseArchitecture: _For every model a representation is saved. This representation contains title(text), type(text), summary(text), content(text), svg(text), updated(date) and created(date). The content is saved as eRDF same as used in client. The **SVG** is saved for a graphical representation. It is a representation of the Oryx-Canvas and enables server-sided export of image formats(pdf,png) without knowledge about stencil sets and shapes._ So fetching your db admin tools and pulling it out of the database should be enough

Comment: Suppose I have something like {\"resourceId\":\"canvas\",\"properties\":{\"name\":\"\",\"documentation\":\"\"},\"stencil\":{\"id\":\"BPMNDiagram\"},\"childShapes\":[{\"resourceId\":\"sid-F534C2............................upperLeft\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0}},\"stencilset\":{\"url\":\"..\\/stencilsets\\/bpmn2.0\\/bpmn2.0.json\",\"namespace\":\"http:\\/\\/b3mn.org\\/stencilset\\/bpmn2.0#\"},\"ssextensions\":[]}   How can I convert this to SVG

Answer (score 3):

The [bpmn-to-image](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-to-image) utility may help you out. It allows you to convert BPMN 2.0 diagrams to images from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you searched for browser plugins like
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-svg-with-style/dkjdcaddoplepioppogpckelchefhddi?hl=en-GB
   ?
2. This thread may be helpful
   [How to save svg canvas to local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483919/how-to-save-svg-canvas-to-local-filesystem)
3. Export the BPMN and load it with another (free) BPMN tool which has export an function, e.g. 
   http://www.bizagi.com/

Comment: Suppose I have something like {\"resourceId\":\"canvas\",\"properties\":{\"name\":\"\",\"documentation\":\"\"}‌​,\"stencil\":{\"id\":\"BPMNDiagram\"},\"childShapes\":[{\"resourceId\":\"sid-F534‌​C2............................upperLeft\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0}},\"stencilset\":{\"ur‌​l\":\"..\\/stencilsets\\/bpmn2.0\\/bpmn2.0.json\",\"namespace\":\"http:\\/\\/b3mn.org\\‌​/stencilset\\/bpmn2.0#\"},\"ssextensions\":[]} How can I convert this to SVG

Comment: This is what I got to be saved from Oryx as a modelData

Comment: Today I would simply use https://bpmn.io/

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for an SVG representation for the BPMN, you can use the recent version of oryx called "Signavio core components". This project save BPMN as .xml file which contains an svg representation... so you can extract it !

Answer (score 0):

There is an SVG diagram generator available written by Martin Grofcik: https://github.com/gro-mar/activiti-crystalball/blob/8e7d3ed387a7a43c92d053a3407788c49c3c4ccb/image-builder/src/main/java/org/activiti/crystalball/diagram/svg/SVGCanvasFactory.java