# (javascript) download SVG containing an image

Tags: image, d3.js, svg, download

I have a visualization (created with d3) that produces an **svg containing an image** (xlink:href to the local image).

Is there any way to download this svg and the image it contains as one unit? If I download it as a png, the contained image doesn't appear. If I download it as an svg, the image is there, but displaced in relation to the other svg elements, for some reason.

Right now the only solution I can think of is asking the visualization user to take a screenshot, which is not ideal...

Comment: Convert the image to a data url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save svg canvas to local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483919/how-to-save-svg-canvas-to-local-filesystem)