# Can't download my svg to png

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, canvg

Can anyone tell me why is my svg to png not downloading? What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find a solution on how to download my svg to png. Is it my libraries or my code?

```js
function save(){
    $("#editor_save").click(function() {
        // the canvg call that takes the svg xml and converts it to a canvas
        canvg('canvas', $("#editor").html());

        // the canvas calls to output a png
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        // do what you want with the base64, write to screen, post to server, etc...
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="canvg-master/canvg.js"></script>
<div id="editor" class="chart">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="red" />
    </svg><br />
    <button id="editor_save" onclick="save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a whole host of issues:

- canvg as its name suggests works on a canvas, you even have a call to `getElementById("canvas")` in the code you've copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11228497/1038015) but despite that you don't actually have a canvas element in your question's markup
- you are using .html() to get the data from the div but the div doesn't just have svg in it, it also has a `<br />` and the button
- you have wrapped the code you've copied inside a save function but the save function isn't called from anywhere
- you've not included the correct canvas scripts properly
- you've not included jQuery but you are using that library

In my corrected code I've left the canvas div visible so you cn see it working. Te canvas would normally be `display:none` though and you'd do something else with the img object.

```js
$("#editor_save").click(function() {

// the canvg call that takes the svg xml and converts it to a canvas
  canvg('canvas', $("#svg")[0].outerHTML);

// the canvas calls to output a png
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
// do what you want with the base64, write to screen, post to server, etc...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://canvg.github.io/canvg/rgbcolor.js"></script>
<script src="http://canvg.github.io/canvg/StackBlur.js"></script>
<script src="http://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script>
<div id="editor" class="chart">
<svg id="svg" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="red" />
</svg>
<br />
<button id="editor_save">Save</button>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Robert thank you for your answer but how do I save it to my browser when you click on save you must save it to my browser how do you do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483919/how-to-save-svg-canvas-to-local-filesystem

Comment: Hey Robert Im new to jquery cant you edit the solution in my code please

Comment: Ask another question, I've corrected the issues in the code you've provided. Be sure to explain why the answers linked to in my other comment don't solve your problem.